# M1 admin issue when click on manage customers

Tags: magento-1.8

Anyone facing this issue in M1 ?

***I get the following error returned when clicking edit or add new customer within the admin panel. customers–> manage customers –> “edit” or “add new customer”***

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File::shutdown() in /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/lib/Zend/Log.php:285 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/Abstract.php(170): Zend_Log->__destruct() #1 /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/Abstract.php(149): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract->_getInputValidateClass() #2 /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(191): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract->getClass() #3 /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/app/code/local/EM/Addphone/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php(43): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array) #4 /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.p in /var/www/vhosts/chroot/www.priceguru.mu/webroot/lib/Zend/Log.php on line 285
```

How do I fix this?

We have not experienced this error before and the code within the files indicated in the error has not changed from prior application versions.

I should also add that when trying to Create a New Order on the backend, the Create New Customer button and links to existing customers do not respond when clicked. Not sure if the errors are related but they started at the same time.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

Have experienced the same problem today, 6 weeks after upgrading to M1.9.4.3.  Completely inexplicable.  None of the Zend files have changed. The shutdown command is undefined.

Can not explain why but workaround for this problem is as follows:-

Comment out this line in lib/Zend/Log.php - Line 366

```
  $writer->shutdown();
```

And comment out this line on line 465

```
$writer->write($event);
```

Obvs not ideal, but gets the store back up and running.